# How can we create QWaylandSurface programatically?

Tags: surface, wayland, qtwayland

How can we create QWaylandSurface programatically?
The current QWindow compositor samples do not provide sufficient details.
Is it to be created using native wayland APIs directly or Qt provides a mechanism to wrap a window object as QWayland surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects and creates a surface, the signal [QWaylandCompositor::surfaceRequested](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaylandcompositor.html#surfaceRequested) is emitted. You can attach a signal handler and instantiate a QWaylandSurface yourself there if you need to do something special.

If you don't create a QWaylandSurface or a derivative in that handler, then a QWaylandSurface is created automatically and will be provided in the  [QWaylandCompositor::surfaceCreated](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaylandcompositor.html#surfaceCreated) signal.